# GWT , SmartGWT error: setRowAriaState is not a function

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have listGrid:

```
private com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.ListGrid listGrid;

        listGrid = new ListGrid() {

        @Override
        protected Canvas createRecordComponent(final ListGridRecord record, Integer colNum) {
            String fieldName = this.getFieldName(colNum);
            if (fieldName.equals("toolStrip")) {
                HLayout canvas = new HLayout();
                canvas.setAlign(VerticalAlignment.TOP);
                canvas.setAutoHeight();
                ToolStrip strip = new ToolStrip();
                strip.setAutoHeight();
                strip.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);
                strip.setWidth(90);
                strip.setHeight(25);

                if (record.getAttributeAsBoolean("requireDoc") && !record.getAttributeAsBoolean("docProvided")) {
                    ToolStripButton requiredDocButton = new ToolStripButton();
                    requiredDocButton.setPrompt(conMess.notProvidedDocsPromt());
                    requiredDocButton.setIcon("attention.png");
                    strip.addButton(requiredDocButton);
                } else {
                    strip.addSpacer(19);
                }

                ToolStripButton pdfButton = new ToolStripButton();
                pdfButton.setPrompt(conMess.lookInPdf());
                pdfButton.setIcon("pdf.png");
                pdfButton.setCursor(Cursor.POINTER);
                pdfButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        service.generatePdfUser(record.getAttributeAsString("type"), record.getAttributeAsDate("startDate"), record.getAttributeAsDate("endDate"),
                                record.getAttributeAsInt("numOfDays"), new AsyncCallback<Void>() {

                                    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                                        String targetURL = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "PdfServlet";
                                        Window.open(targetURL, "", null);
                                    }

                                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                });
                strip.addButton(pdfButton);

                ToolStripButton deleteRecordButton = new ToolStripButton();
                deleteRecordButton.setIcon("document_delete.png");

                Date formStartDate = record.getAttributeAsDate("startDate");
                if ((formStartDate.getMonth() > lastLockedMonth && formStartDate.after(currentDate)) || formStartDate.getYear() > currentDate.getYear()) {
                    deleteRecordButton.setDisabled(false);
                    deleteRecordButton.setPrompt(conMess.deleteForm());
                    deleteRecordButton.setCursor(Cursor.POINTER);
                } else {
                    deleteRecordButton.setDisabled(true);
                    deleteRecordButton.setPrompt(conMess.deleteMessagePromt());
                }
                deleteRecordButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        SC.ask(conMess.deletingForm(), conMess.askingForDeleteVerification(), new BooleanCallback() {

                            public void execute(Boolean value) {
                                if (value) {
                                    listGrid.removeData(record);
                                    service.updateUserInfoOnRedraw(new AsyncCallback<User>() {

                                        public void onSuccess(User result) {
                                            redrawHeader();
                                        }

                                        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                                            GWT.log(caught.getMessage());
                                            SC.say(caught.getMessage());
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                if (record.getAttributeAsInt("userId").equals(record.getAttributeAsInt("userCreatorId"))) {
                    strip.addButton(deleteRecordButton);
                } else {
                    strip.addSpacer(20);
                }
                canvas.addMember(strip);
                return canvas;
            }
            return null;
        }
    };


listGrid.setHeaderAutoFitEvent(AutoFitEvent.NONE);
    listGrid.setWidth100(); 
    listGrid.setShowHeaderContextMenu(false);
    listGrid.setShowHeaderMenuButton(false);

    listGrid.setAutoFetchData(false);
    listGrid.setShowRecordComponents(true);
    listGrid.setShowRecordComponentsByCell(true);
    listGrid.setCanEdit(false);
    listGrid.setLayoutAlign(Alignment.CENTER);
    listGrid.setLeaveScrollbarGap(true); listGrid.setCellHeight(25);

    dataSource = FormulaireDataSource.getInstance();
    listGrid.setDataSource(dataSource);
    listGrid.setFields(formId, userId, type, formSent, numOfDays, startDate, endDate, stage_one, stage_one_text, stage_two, stage_two_text, status, status_text, toolStrip, userCreatorId,
            requireDoc, docProvided);
    // dataSource.fetchData();
    listGrid.fetchData();
    listGrid.invalidateCache();
    listGrid.setHeaderHeight(30);
    listGrid.setCanResizeFields(false);
    listGrid.sort("startDate", SortDirection.DESCENDING);
    listGrid.setCanSort(true);
```

It throws this exception on row listGrid.fetchData() (from the code above):

```
    [ERROR] [Vacations] - 15:54:38.884:MDN9:WARN:Log:TypeError: this.setRowAriaState is not a function
Stack from error.stack:
    GridBody.updateRowSelection() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:689
    GridRenderer._rowSelectionChanged() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:557
    GridRenderer._setSelectedObservation() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:556
    anonymous() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:49
    Selection.select() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:198
    Selection.selectSingle() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:198
    Selection.selectOnMouseDown() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:204
    GridRenderer.selectOnMouseDown() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:557
    [a]MathFunction.invokeSuper() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:233
    GridBody.selectOnMouseDown() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:680
    GridRenderer._cellMouseDown() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:557
    GridRenderer.mouseDown() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:557
    Canvas.handleMouseDown() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:2196
    [c]EventHandler.bubbleEvent() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:1220
    [c]EventHandler.doHandleMouseDown() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:1053
    [c]EventHandler.handleMouseDown() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:1044
    [c]EventHandler.dispatch() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:1252
    anonymous() @ Vacations/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:43
    unnamed() @
```

I generally cannot run the project. Is old project and it worked with:
GWT 2.5.0
smartgwt 3.0

Now it's with:
GWT 2.6.0
smartgwt 4.0

I did try with smartgwt 5.0p as well but there was error for not loading SmartGWTEntryPoint or something like this. All smartGWT versions are LGPL versions. Home page of the project is loading and when I try to go to the listGrid I see the error. In google there is nothing about this error. I don't know what more to add. I did try to clean browser cache , to recompile and to debug  many many times. Please help!

.classpath:

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.GAE_CONTAINER/App Engine"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="test"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER/GWT"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/apache-poi-3.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.25.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-labs.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-endpoints-deps.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-endpoints.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-jsr107cache-1.9.25.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-cal-0.9.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-dnd-3.3.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-servlet.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/itext-5.1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/jsr107cache-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/mail-1.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/smartgwt-skins.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/smartgwt.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-user-2.6.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

**When testing with GWT 2.7, smartGWT 5.0p, Google SDK 1.9.28, super dev mode the browser loads blank page. Result from the console :**

```
The code server is ready at http://127.0.0.1:9876/
Code server started in 26386 ms
waited 8843 ms for code server to finish
GET /recompile/Vacations
   Job projectCongees.Vacations_2_0
      starting job: projectCongees.Vacations_2_0
      binding: locale=bg
      Compiling module projectCongees.Vacations
         Unification traversed 51666 fields and methods and 3737 types. 3702 are considered part of the current module and 3702 had all of their fields and methods traversed.
         Compiling 1 permutation
            Compiling permutation 0...
            Linking per-type JS with 3686 new types.
               prelink JS size = 10734929
               prelink sourcemap = 10734929 bytes and 277033 lines
               postlink JS size = 10632028
               postlink sourcemap = 10632028 bytes and 274310 lines
            Source Maps Enabled
         Compile of permutations succeeded
         Compilation succeeded -- 24.587s
      Linking into /tmp/gwt-codeserver-3860455776220907037.tmp/projectCongees.Vacations/compile-2/war/Vacations; Writing extras to /tmp/gwt-codeserver-3860455776220907037.tmp/projectCongees.Vacations/compile-2/extras/Vacations
         Link succeeded
         Linking succeeded -- 3.424s
      29.906s total -- Compile completed
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a version incompatibility problem, when you compile a SmartGWT project, GWT compiler copies some .js files to your destination folder (under `YOUR_MODULE_NAME/sc` directory), try to delete `sc` folder from your web application and recompile your project and then let me know if your have still same issue.

Comment: Neither deleting Vacation/sc, neither deleting  gwt-UnitCache helps. I delete these folders, Right Click , Google-> GWT Compile. There are two errors:

Comment: Errors in 'com/smartgwt/client/bean/types/EnumValueType.java'
         Line 26: Name clash: The method registerValueType(Class<T>) of type EnumValueType<ValueType> has the same erasure as registerValueType(Class<T>) of type OtherValueType<ValueType> but does not hide it
      Errors in 'com/smartgwt/client/bean/types/JsoValueType.java'
         Line 31: Name clash: The method registerValueType(Class<T>) of type JsoValueType<ValueType> has the same erasure as registerValueType(Class<T>) of type OtherValueType<ValueType> but does not hide it

Comment: But the project is compiled. After that running the project via -> Debug -> GWT classic dev mode. The login page is loading, then I log in, then after navigating to the page with the list grid I see the error from the question. Themese are loading. I will try to share the project in bit bucket if you like?

Comment: Are you sure that you are compiling with the new GWT and SmartGWT jar files in your project build path? If yes, then please retry in super dev mode

Comment: I'm not compiling with smartGWT 5.0p which is the last version as I know. I'm compiling with smartGWT 4.0. With 5.0p there is completely different error.  I'm adding my classpath file in the question . Running the app in super dev mode loads empty page without any messages in the development console, and in the console as well.

Comment: I did try with everything new: Google SDK 1.9.28,GWT 2.7, smartGWT 5.0p and the result is blank page although everything compiles and runs in super dev mode. I will add the result from the console in my question for this run

Comment: super dev mode compiles whole client side code to javascript and then run it. So unlike deprecated classic mode (which is not supported by most browsers anymore), it has no client side debug capability and this is a very big problem while you have complex client application. So try to compile your project in detailed mode (instead of obfuscated mode) and sorround your error prone code sections with try catch block, it may help you to find source of error.